# "Interesting" pattern when plotting ratio between natural numbers and the sum of their closest factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was playing around with graphing numbers recently and an interesting pattern emerged. I was plotting them on a cartesian plane with points $(x, y)$ where $x$ is each of the natural numbers, and $y$ is the ratio of the number itself divided by the sum of its closest pair of factors. For example, the point where $x = 12$ would be $(12, \frac{12}{7})$. Below is the graph I got for the first 1000 numbers. Also, what is interesting is that I thought since the y-coordinate is a ratio it wouldn't get significantly larger as x tends towards larger numbers but it doesn't seem so.

[image here because stackexchange doesn't let me embed images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqKkH.png)

Is this supposed to happen? Am I just being stupid?

Comment: At the very least, if $x$ is a perfect square then the point in question is $(x,\frac12\sqrt x)$, which is going to grow. (Or take $x=(n-1)(n+1)$ if you want distinct factors.) So I'm not surprised to see an upper envelope that looks like a sideways parabola.

Comment: In general, AM-GM gives $x+\frac xd\ge 2\sqrt{x}$, so $\frac12\sqrt{x}$ is an upper bound. As Greg Martin notes, this bound is sharp.

Comment: Thanks. That part makes sense, but what about the smaller layered parabolas inside the upper bound? How would one explain that?